# primefaces: how to disable css in <p:layoutUnit>

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, primefaces

i'm using `<p:layout>` and `<p:layoutUnit>` to organise the structure of my web page, and primefaces add his own css to the content here are some images to help you understand :

**befor :**
[image]
**After :**

[image]

and i want to know if there is away to only disable the css of `<p:layoutUnit>`.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the style class for the desired unit:

- `ui-layout-unit` for all the layout units
- `ui-layout-{position}` for a layout unit in a specific position

[There's no magic bullet to unset every CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782010/how-to-remove-every-style-from-element), so you need to override a specific property as in:

1. Override the CSS class in your view

   ```
   .your-custom-theme-elem .ui-layout-unit {
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
   }
   ```
2. Apply the custom class to the layout unit

   ```
    <p:layoutUnit styleClass=".your-custom-theme-elem" position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
         <h:outputText value="North unit content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>
   ```